# Not able to connect to Photon(PUN).photon unity networking error

Tags: unity, photon

I'm new to photon Networking. My game was working great suddenly this is appearing

Cannot send messages when not connected. Either connect to Photon OR use offline mode! UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the player already in the scene and try to connect again. The PUN is trying to connect the player with the server.. Hope this will solve your problem.

All The Best

Answer (score 0):

This is mine part of code, which is used to connect to the room by client

```
void OnConnectedToMaster() {
    RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions () { isVisible = false, maxPlayers = 5 };
    PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom ("TestRoom", roomOptions, TypedLobby.Default);
}

void OnJoinedRoom() {
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Player", spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation, 0);
}
```

I guess they've changed something in API (using PUN only for the first day), but this is the code snippet which helped me to get it up and running (others were outdated and using `OnJoinedLobby` method.

I hope it will help you to solve your problem.